# What's the limit of GM forcing things for the players' enjoyment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, dice

We all know the dice's outcomes may be unpleasant, expecially in the case of story events, when players may feel that they had no control on something except rolling the dice higher.

Should the master force things a bit in these situations, or should the dice, even the ones he rolls behind the screen, have an undebatable verdict?

Comment: Hi Earendil. Whether or not a GM can/should fudge ever is more or less a matter of opinion (you'll find people arguing yes or no), but we've also got advice covered on how to handle the prospect of fudging, or the felt need to fudge, in another question I've pointed this one to as a duplicate.